# Prove that $(1+1/a)^{a+1}<(1+1/b)^{b+1}$ if $a>b>0$

Tags: real-analysis, euler-mascheroni-constant

The problem: Prove that

$(1+1/a)^{a+1}<(1+1/b)^{b+1}$ if $a>b>0$.

I have tried to prove this by obtaining the derivate of $(1+1/x)^{x+1}$:

$\frac{d}{dx}(1+1/x)^{x+1}=((1 + 1/x)^x (1 + x) (-1 + x \ln(1 + 1/x)))/x^2$

and showing  $x \ln(1 + 1/x)$ is less than $1$ on $x>0$. But I failed.

It is curious that $(1+1/x)^{x+1}$ decrease on $x>0$ but $(1+1/x)^x$ is increase on $x>0$.

How can we prove this?

Comment: One answer is given in Theorem 1 at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4622073/945479.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that the function
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1} = \exp f(x),
\quad \text{with}\quad
f(x) := (x+1)\log(1+1/x),\quad x>0,
$$
is decreasing in $(0, +\infty)$, which amounts to prove that $f$ is decreasing
in the same interval.

Computing the derivative you get
$$
f'(x) = \log(1+1/x) - 1/x < 0 \qquad \forall x>0,
$$
since $\log(1+t) \leq t$ for every $t> -1$ (with strict inequality for $t\neq 0$).

Comment: Thank you. This is a good idea.